# Switzerland travel plan

Tags: london, tips-and-tricks, switzerland, zurich, geneva

I need some guidance on my travel plans.

I have booked my return tickets from London to Geneva for August bank holiday.

I'll have 3 complete days to visit place/places.

After I booked, I realized that I should have booked my return flight from Zurich (London to Geneva and Zurich to London) because I would like to visit Zurich as well in the same trip. However flight tickets are not changeable which means in between my trip I'll have to make two journeys: Geneva to Zurich and then again Zurich to Geneva to catch my flight back.

I am checking online for Geneva to Zurich travel options, and it seems train takes around 2.5 hours for one side travel and costs 65 pounds, which is more expensive than my Geneva to London flight ticket.

**Keeping Zurich**

1) Is it possible to travel from Geneva to Zurich and vice versa by some other means of public transport which is bit cheaper? I can't drive.

2) Is it possible to make these journeys by different route to make these journeys also pleasant and worthwhile?

**Cancelling Zurich**

I don't visit Zurich in this trip if Geneva and other places nearby are so good to spend 3 days?

I am really confused now, how shall I plan this trip to make the most out of it, and spend money on other better things.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions. Please feel free to ask more details if you need that for providing suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Consider splitting your questions, some are considered opinion-based (the last 2 for example) and might be closed

Comment: I would probably recommend cancelling Zürich, at least this time around. You're very unlikely to find a significantly cheaper price - unfortunately, public transport in particular is very expensive in Switzerland. If you had booked your return flight from there it sure would have been worth a visit, but in your current situation I don't think it would be worth the time and money. But how about this: You could focus more on the french speaking part of Switzerland, and make a trip to Gruyères via Lausanne and Montreux.

Comment: Both [Lausanne](https://www.google.com/search?q=Lausanne&tbm=isch) and [Montreux](https://www.google.com/search?q=Montreux&tbm=isch) are nice lakeside cities worth a visit, and [Gruyères](https://www.google.com/search?q=Gruyères&tbm=isch) is a quaint medieval town on top of a hill that has quite a few [tourist attractions](http://www.la-gruyere.ch/en/Destinations/Gruyeres/) in a small area (Cheese Factory and H.R. Giger Museum for example). This route would be about 45 CHF one way (~ 31 GBP).

Answer (score 1):

1. You can maybe find some private bus company unless there are rules that ban this, it might be cheaper but will surely take longer and you risk getting stuck in traffic.
2. yes, by using the mountain railways on the alps, but it costs a lot and they are pretty far off from Zürich so it would take a long time, not a good idea without any stops in the middle.
3. this is a personal decision, only you know how much your time is worth
4. if you don't like Geneva you can go visit nearby areas or other cities in French Switzerland much closer than Zürich, or enjoy the lake and landscape. Even Bern is closer than Zürich and it's nice to visit.
5. opinion based, general rule that applies to travel imho: keep it simple, don't spend more time traveling than visiting stuff (unless you're on an alpine railway, there are many of these in Switzerland).

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I am not able to vote up because not having enough reputation.